# logcat error when running application in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

For some reason when I run the application and check logcat, it gives me this really long log. Is anything here really important that I should fix?

This log starts to show as soon as I start the application.

```
    09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.742        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.743        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.743        0-939/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
09-23 12:15:56.976      929-929/? E/lowmemorykiller﹕ Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer
09-23 12:15:57.641      932-932/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
09-23 12:15:57.856     932-1018/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-23 12:16:00.281      939-939/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
09-23 12:16:00.283      939-939/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
09-23 12:16:00.295    1210-1210/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
09-23 12:16:00.301      939-939/? E/Netd﹕ failed to flush rules
09-23 12:16:00.301      939-939/? E/CommandListener﹕ failed to initialize RouteController (Remote I/O error)
09-23 12:16:01.856      946-946/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:01.856      946-946/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-23 12:16:02.613     943-1228/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ no wake lock to update!
09-23 12:16:02.615      943-943/? E/audio_hw_generic﹕ Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
09-23 12:16:02.615      943-943/? E/AudioFlinger﹕ int android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:02.616      943-943/? E/SoundTriggerHwService﹕ couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:02.743      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.743      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujarati-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.743      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujaratiUI-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.743      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGujaratiUI-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.744      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhi-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.744      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhi-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.744      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.744      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGurmukhiUI-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.790      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.790      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSinhala-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansThaana-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansThaana-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCham-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCham-Bold.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansBalinese-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansBatak-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.813      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansBuginese-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansBuhid-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCanadianAboriginal-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCherokee-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansCoptic-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansGlagolitic-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansHanunoo-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansJavanese-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansKayahLi-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansLepcha-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansLimbu-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansMeeteiMayek-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansOlChiki-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansRejang-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.814      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSaurashtra-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSundanese-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansSylotiNagri-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansTagbanwa-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansTaiLe-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansTaiTham-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansTaiViet-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansTifinagh-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansYi-Regular.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/Lohit-Odia.ttf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansHans-Regular.otf
09-23 12:16:02.815      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansHant-Regular.otf
09-23 12:16:02.816      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansJP-Regular.otf
09-23 12:16:02.816      946-946/? E/Minikin﹕ addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NotoSansKR-Regular.otf
09-23 12:16:03.470      946-946/? E/EmojiFactory_jni﹕ Failed to load libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found
09-23 12:16:06.454    1232-1232/system_process E/PowerManagerService-JNI﹕ Couldn't load power module (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:06.501     932-1020/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
09-23 12:16:10.667    1232-1232/system_process E/ConsumerIrService﹕ Can't open consumer IR HW Module, error: -2
09-23 12:16:11.109    1232-1286/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
09-23 12:16:11.125    1232-1286/system_process E/EventHub﹕ could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
09-23 12:16:11.967    1232-1232/system_process E/WifiConfigStore﹕ associatedPartialScanPeriodMilli set to 20000
09-23 12:16:12.523    1232-1232/system_process E/Fingerprint-JNI﹕ Can't open fingerprint HW Module, error: -2
09-23 12:16:12.583    1232-1232/system_process E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 16 frames from WAL file /data/system/locksettings.db-wal
09-23 12:16:12.617    1232-1232/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage﹕ Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:12.617    1232-1232/system_process E/LockSettingsStorage﹕ Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:13.281    1232-1312/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:13.282    1232-1312/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:13.299    1232-1232/system_process E/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Ignoring setImeWindowStatus due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
09-23 12:16:13.422    1380-1387/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
09-23 12:16:13.450     943-1399/? E/WVMExtractor﹕ Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
09-23 12:16:14.016    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:14.017    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
09-23 12:16:14.084    1232-1232/system_process E/FlpHardwareProvider﹕ Error hw_get_module 'flp': -2
09-23 12:16:14.085    1232-1232/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ FLP HAL not supported
09-23 12:16:14.087    1232-1232/system_process E/ActivityRecognitionHardware﹕ Error hw_get_module: -2
09-23 12:16:14.087    1232-1232/system_process E/LocationManagerService﹕ Hardware Activity-Recognition not supported.
09-23 12:16:14.416    1232-1249/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:14.751    1461-1480/android.process.media E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
09-23 12:16:16.078    1461-1461/android.process.media E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 94 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db-wal
09-23 12:16:16.416    1232-1232/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:16.497    1232-1232/system_process E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:16.855    1630-1637/? E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
09-23 12:16:18.931    1516-1701/com.android.phone E/DcSwitchStateMachine-0﹕ DctController is not ready
09-23 12:16:19.104    1232-1304/system_process E/ConnectivityService﹕ Failed to find Messenger in unregisterNetworkFactory
09-23 12:16:19.179    1516-1516/com.android.phone E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:19.476    1344-1344/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:25.373    1344-1344/com.android.systemui E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:30.375      932-932/? E/EGL_emulation﹕ tid 932: eglCreateSyncKHR(1237): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-23 12:16:36.201    1826-1859/com.google.process.gapps E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2172)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2148)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:671)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.an.<init>(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.f(SourceFile:248)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.b(SourceFile:196)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:131)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-23 12:16:36.616    1741-1857/com.google.process.location E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2172)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2148)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:671)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.an.<init>(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.f(SourceFile:248)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupTransportMigratorService.d(SourceFile:31)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.y.a(SourceFile:97)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.y.doInBackground(SourceFile:93)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-23 12:16:37.449    1878-1878/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:37.449    1878-1878/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-23 12:16:37.667    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:37.667    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
09-23 12:16:37.709    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:37.709    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
09-23 12:16:38.219    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:38.219    1232-1232/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
09-23 12:16:38.529    1232-1304/system_process E/ConnectivityService﹕ Exception in setupDataActivityTracking java.lang.IllegalStateException: command '14 idletimer add eth0 5 0' failed with '400 14 Failed to add interface'
09-23 12:16:38.571    1826-1916/com.google.process.gapps E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2172)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2148)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:671)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.an.<init>(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.a.a(SourceFile:66)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.c.a(SourceFile:40)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:69)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:40)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupAccountNotifierService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:76)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-23 12:16:38.577    1826-1916/com.google.process.gapps E/Backup﹕ [LegacyBackupAccountManager] Fail to get legacy transport context.
    android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Application package com.google.android.backup not found
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2172)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2148)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:671)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.an.<init>(SourceFile:47)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.a.a(SourceFile:66)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.c.a(SourceFile:40)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:69)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.b.a(SourceFile:40)
            at com.google.android.gms.backup.BackupAccountNotifierService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:76)
            at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
09-23 12:16:38.741    1232-1249/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no AGPS interface in set_agps_server
09-23 12:16:38.755    1232-1249/system_process E/GpsLocationProvider﹕ no GPS configuration interface in configuraiton_update
09-23 12:16:39.632    1960-1985/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (284) automatic index on assetrefs(dataitems_id)
09-23 12:16:43.705    1999-1999/com.google.android.apps.maps E/BluetoothAdapter﹕ Bluetooth binder is null
09-23 12:16:44.043    2058-2065/com.android.deskclock E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
09-23 12:16:45.284    1826-1840/com.google.process.gapps E/SQLiteLog﹕ (283) recovered 6 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/playlog.db-wal
09-23 12:16:45.767    2136-2143/com.google.android.gms.unstable E/art﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
09-23 12:16:45.853     943-1230/? E/Drm﹕ Failed to find drm plugin
09-23 12:16:47.046    2191-2191/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
09-23 12:16:47.046    2191-2191/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
09-23 12:16:47.129    2191-2201/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1
09-23 12:16:47.244    2204-2204/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.cade.codigos, PID: 2204
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {org.cade.codigos/org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.cade.codigos.ui.components.CustomWebView.getUrl()' on a null object reference
```

Thanks.

Comment: are you debugging your app? or the full phone logcat? because... that looks like your full phone logcat and thousand of things happen in background all the time.

Comment: Mariano thanks for quick response , your the best!

i was not debugging just running the emulator and checked the logcat, i should debugg when checking for this errors?

Comment: if the logcat runs all the time without a targeting app... your logcat goes crazy (google apps, background apps, etc etc). Ones you launch the app, that'll be target and only show you what happen with that app and that app only. Also, if you Log your code, use your TAG to search only that info.

Answer (score 3):

Logcat shows logs for all applications/processes running inside your Device.

Use TAG to find logs for your application.

```
Log.d("TAG","your custom message");
```

Next in android studio, enter your `TAG` name in the search field right to `"Log Level:"` message in `"Android"` tab.

You will get your logs specific to your application.

Otherwise just search for the application package name.