# android studio understand error

Tags: java, android, logcat

I am trying to learn android Studio.I have a question about `Logcat` and need to understand the error output.

I am getting this error message and I don't know what to do.
I have searched a lot but i don't see any blue link or I can't see what is missing.

```
<pre><code>
05-15 14:38:22.501 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/jdwp/jdwp_event.cc:661] Check failed: Thread::Current() != GetDebugThread() (Thread::Current()=0xa6409400, GetDebugThread()=0xa6409400) Expected event thread
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Runtime aborting...
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] Aborting thread:
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingForDebuggerSend
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c21f70 self=0xa6409400
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2430 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa952920
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaa856000-0xaa858000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
05-15 14:38:23.036 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc 00572f1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
...
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 Waiting
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c27160 self=0xa1c37700
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2432 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa74e920
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaa64c000-0xaa64e000 stackSize=1038KB
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
05-15 14:38:23.043 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
...
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - waiting on <0x0f8a0caa> (a java.lang.Object)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   - locked <0x0f8a0caa> (a java.lang.Object)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:204)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Binder:2423_1" prio=5 tid=9 Native
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c273a0 self=0xa1c38600
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2435 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaa341920
05-15 14:38:23.044 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xaa245000-0xaa247000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0xb9a/0xd63
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2af/0x6c9
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x36b/0x415
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x4a/0x6a
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077b8c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+28)
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000226d7  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+71)
05-15 14:38:23.045 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00047797  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+279)
...
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Binder:2423_2" prio=5 tid=10 Native
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c27430 self=0xa640a800
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2436 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xa48ac920
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0xa47b0000-0xa47b2000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0xb9a/0xd63
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x2af/0x6c9
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x36b/0x415
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x4a/0x6a
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077b8c  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+28)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 000226d7  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+71)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00047797  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+279)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0004793a  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+42)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 000481ff  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+95)
05-15 14:38:23.047 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0006effe  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android10PoolThread10threadLoopEv+46)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00012095  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+309)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Profile Saver" prio=5 tid=11 Native
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c57af0 self=0xab70c300
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2560 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x941c3920
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x940c7000-0x940c9000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0011d1de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+142)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0011d147  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+39)
05-15 14:38:23.048 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 003c955c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver3RunEv+396)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 003cb66a  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver21RunProfileSaverThreadEPv+106)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "Thread-3" prio=5 tid=12 Native
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c5d9d0 self=0x9fc6aa00
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2562 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9408e920
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x93f8c000-0x93f8e000 stackSize=1038KB
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.049 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: __skb_recv_datagram+0x198/0x1ef
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: skb_recv_datagram+0x28/0x2a
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: unix_accept+0x48/0xf2
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_accept4+0xfa/0x1b4
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_socketcall+0x1b9/0x1db
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 00077819  /system/lib/libc.so (__accept4+25)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00000ce3  /system/lib/libnetd_client.so (???)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0001ef17  /system/lib/libc.so (accept4+55)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001eed6  /system/lib/libc.so (accept+54)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00023808  /system/lib/libjavacore.so (???)
05-15 14:38:23.050 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 0029ab3c  /system/framework/x86/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_libcore_io_Posix_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_net_SocketAddress_2+168)

05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x23c/0x2d1
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0x70/0xe1
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe424  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+16)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0007790b  /system/lib/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+43)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 00020cb0  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_pwait+112)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 00020d0e  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+62)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 00018f1b  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+203)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 00018d84  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+68)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00035408  /system/lib/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+888)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00012095  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+309)
05-15 14:38:23.051 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #10 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #11 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #12 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "hwuiTask1" prio=5 tid=14 Native
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d44a60 self=0xa6409900
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2627 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x9307f920
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x92f83000-0x92f85000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
05-15 14:38:23.052 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0007454d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+125)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0003643b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001202f  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+207)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] "hwuiTask2" prio=5 tid=15 Native
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x12d44af0 self=0x9f9e1200
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | sysTid=2628 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x92f80920
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
05-15 14:38:23.053 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | stack=0x92e84000-0x92e86000 stackSize=1014KB
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   | held mutexes=
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xcd/0x113
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: futex_wait+0xc1/0x194
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: do_futex+0x9b/0x740
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xaf/0xf6
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   kernel: sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #00 pc ffffe422  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+14)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #01 pc 0001e258  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #02 pc 0007454d  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+125)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #03 pc 0003643b  /system/lib/libhwui.so (???)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #04 pc 0001202f  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+207)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #05 pc 0007098b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+111)
05-15 14:38:23.054 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #06 pc 00011883  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS_+259)
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #07 pc 00074fe2  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+210)
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #08 pc 0002029e  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+30)
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   native: #09 pc 0001e076  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422]   (no managed stack frames)
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:422] 

                                                             --------- beginning of crash
05-15 14:38:23.055 2423-2430/testproject.mycompany.com A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2430 (JDWP)

                                                              [ 05-15 14:38:23.055  1275: 1275 W/         ]
                                                              debuggerd: handling request: pid=2423 uid=10073 gid=10073 tid=2430


</code></pre>
```

If the update generates the error then where I can see all the packages and how can I remove updates if I need it.

And how can i understand the error in Logcat?

Comment: You should try simple way to ask the question. Don't drag it too much stating I was able to solve issues but now not getting anything.

Comment: problem solved. I know that I put to much statements but otherwise I dont understand the error msg. So I've put the lines maybe anthoerMember can understand it better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [logcat error when running application in AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739490/logcat-error-when-running-application-in-androidstudio)